# Multiple Lists into Single List based on Index

Tags: python, list, indexing

I'm new to python and I'm trying to merge three different lists into one list based on the index value as shown in the example below:
All three lists are of same size.

```
A=['ABC', 'PQR', 'MNO']
B=['X', 'Y', 'Z']
C=['1','2','3']***
```

The output that I wanted is
P=[['ABC', 'X', '1'],['PQR', 'Y', '2'],['MNO', 'Z', '3']]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out the `zip` function.

Comment: Specifically, `list(zip(A,B,C))` will give you a list of tuples with the contents you want. If you explicitly want a list of lists, you could do `list(map(list, zip(A,B,C)))`

Comment: `list(zip(A,B,C))` is a list of tuples. Use `[list(n) for n in list(zip(A,B,C))]` if you need list of lists.

Comment: `map` does the same, it is advantaged for beginners.

Comment: @DanSmith If you find any answer helpful for you, accept it to close the question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution for you using the `for loop` with the `range()` function:

```
A=['ABC', 'PQR', 'MNO']
B=['X', 'Y', 'Z']
C=['1','2','3']

list1=[]
for i in range(len(A)):
    list1.append([A[i],B[i],C[i]])

display(list1)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[['ABC', 'X', '1'], ['PQR', 'Y', '2'], ['MNO', 'Z', '3']]
```

Using `for loop` with the `zip()` function:

```
l=[]
for a,b,c in zip(A,B,C):
    l.append([a,b,c])
    
display(l)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[['ABC', 'X', '1'], ['PQR', 'Y', '2'], ['MNO', 'Z', '3']]
```

You don't want to use `for loop`?

Then here is the `map()` function for you:

```
result = list(map(lambda a, b, c: [a,b,c] , A, B,C))
display(result)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[['ABC', 'X', '1'], ['PQR', 'Y', '2'], ['MNO', 'Z', '3']]
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually do it with numpy, as it is a simple traspose, and works with as many lists as you throw at it:

```
import numpy as np

A = ['ABC', 'PQR', 'MNO']
B = ['X', 'Y', 'Z']
C = ['1', '2', '3']

lists = [A, B, C]
numpy_array = np.array(lists)

transpose = numpy_array.T
transpose_list = transpose.tolist()

print(transpose_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use list comprehension to get desired output;

```
a=[[x,y,z] for x,y,z in zip(A,B,C)]
print(a)
```